# Hide div when other div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

How do I toggle so when I have one `div` open and I click the other one it closes? Here is my Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.expander').live('click', function () {
        $('#TableData').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
     $('.expander2').live('click', function () {
        $('#TableData2').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Can you explain what's not working right now? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `live()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. Use the delegated form of `on()` instead, assuming you're using a version of jQuery newer than 1.7 (which you really should be)

Comment: Sorry. I have 2 buttons and when I click one button it expands. When I click the 2nd button it expands below it. I want to be able to when I click one and then I click the other one the 1st one I clicked closes and only the 2nd one is exposed. I only want 1 div to show at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#TableData").hide();
 $(".expander").show();
 
 $('.expander').click(function(){
 $("#TableData").slideToggle();
 return false;
 });
 
 $("#TableData2").hide();
 $(".expander2").show();
 
 $('.expander2').click(function(){
 $("#TableData2").slideToggle();
 return false;
 });
 
 });
```

```css
#TableData2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class=expander>Expander</button>
<button class=expander2>Expander 2</button>

<hr>
<div id=TableData>TableData1</div>



<div id=TableData2>TableData2</div>
```

Comment: One more question. If I wanted to make it so when I clicked the button with the div already open to make it close again how would I go about doing that?

Comment: add a IF statement if it is visible - hide else show

Comment: Can you provide an example please? I'm new to javascrpt so I dont really get the syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have really helped me out big time today.

Comment: Hi Lucky, Do you think you can help me with the if statements like you did before to have the div closed when the other one is open?